# How does one generically duplicate a value in Rust?

Tags: rust

Primitives should be passed by value as usual and anything that is passed by reference ('borrowed') should be cloned. Something like:

```
let a = 7;
let b = duplicate(a);  // let b = a;

let a = struct{}{};
let b = duplicate(a);  // let b = a.clone();
```

This assumes that every value in Rust implements either the `Clone` or the `Copy` trait. Is this assumption true? If not, is it possible to define a trait `Duplicate` that is kind of an `enum { Clone, Copy }`?

Comment: `struct{}{}` is not valid Rust syntax.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> This assumes that every value in Rust implements either the `Clone` or the `Copy` trait. Is this assumption true?

No.

> is it possible to define a trait `Duplicate`

Yes, but it doesn't seem to serve any value beyond what the existing `Clone` trait does.

---

You may wish to learn more about ownership, as you can make your code compile without doing any cloning at all:

```
fn duplicate<T>(x: T) -> T { x } // sic

fn main() {
    let a = 7;
    let b = duplicate(a);

    let a = String::from("example");
    let b = duplicate(a);
}
```

If you actually want to duplicate, just use `Clone`, as [anything that implements `Copy` must implement `Clone`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html):

```
pub trait Copy: Clone { }
```

You will usually see it as the method syntax:

```
fn main() {
    let a = 7;
    let b: i32 = a.clone();

    let a = String::from("example");
    let b: String = a.clone();
}
```

If you want a function, use the fully-qualified syntax:

```
fn main() {
    let a = 7;
    let b: i32 = Clone::clone(&a);

    let a = String::from("example");
    let b: String = Clone::clone(&a);
}
```

Or

```
fn main() {
    let a = 7;
    let b: i32 = i32::clone(&a);

    let a = String::from("example");
    let b: String = String::clone(&a);
}
```

All the explicit types (`: foo`) are redundant here, just for demonstration purposes.

Comment: Doesn't your proposed `duplicate` function take ownership of `x`? That is exactly what I wanted to circumvent.

Comment: @tillyboy yes, which is why I added `// sic` to it. The code you've written doesn't show any need for anything else.

Answer (score 4):

`Copy` implies `Clone`. You can just use `.clone()` for your duplicate function.

Answer (score -1):

```
unsafe fn duplicate <T> (item: &T) -> T {
  std::ptr::read(item)
}
```

***EDIT - USER DISCRETION ADVISED:***

- When the type is not self-memory-managed, it may or may not exist in-memory as the same type, or it may be that the memory is no longer accessible, in which case a SEGFAULT would occur.
- For any type, non-Copy or not, it will do a bitwise copy of the memory area based on the layout of the type.. It will not do nested copying by dereferencing addresses, it will copy the references/addresses; ie, shallow-copy (from the language-agnostic taxonomy).

For any Copy type, this should be A-OK, but not useful?

I think a use-case for this, is in some situation when a type may not implement Copy and Clone because another trait requires it does not implement it, and so when one wants to move it to another scope/variable/thread one would read it's memory directly.

***I'm not sure though, comment if you have a use-case!***

Comment: This invoke UB for nearly every non-`Copy` type, especially ones that manage any resource, such as `String` or `Vec<T>`